# How to say "by" in French as in "What do you mean by"

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

How do you say "by" in French as in "What do you mean by that" do you use the word "par"?

Also a bit out of topic, how do you say "It can improve your memory a lot" do you use "un beaucoup"? Because it doesn't sound right as "Il peut améliorer ton mémoire un beaucoup". But it sounds better as "Il peut améliorer un beaucoup de ton mémoire" but that's litteraly "It can improve a lot of your memory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be either:

> Qu'est-ce que tu veux dire par là ?

or

> Qu'est ce que tu veux dire avec ça ?

*Beaucoup* isn't used with an article.

*Il peut améliorer un beaucoup de ton mémoire* has multiple issues, I would say:

> Ça peut beaucoup améliorer ta mémoire.

Comment: "avec ça" n'est pas approprié (mais pas incorrect), et ne s'emploie pas souvent. "par là" est le plus utilisé.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Oui, « par là » est bien l'expression la plus utilisée. J'ai mis « dire avec ça » qui peut être employé dans le langage familier pour donner un exemple où le *that* est conservé.

Answer (score 0):

Dans tous les cas, *by that* peut se traduire simplement en *par là*, dans des expressions qui expriment une opinion, une affirmation, une pensée:

> Que voulez-vous **dire par là** ?
>
> Que voulez-vous **affirmer par là** ?
>
> Que voulez-vous **exprimer par là** ?
>
> Qu'**entendez**-vous **par là** ?
>
> A quoi **pensez**-vous **par là** ?

Comment: Jamais entendu « A quoi pensez-vous par là ? ». *By* ne se traduit pas toujours par « par », ex :  *Que veux tu dire par ça ?* ne se dit pas.

Comment: @jlliagre , effectivement, il faut les deux  "par là" . corrigé

Comment: Ngram ne trouve aucune occurrence de « A quoi pensez-vous par là ? ».

Comment: À mon avis c'est que _par là_ signifie _par ces mots_, et donc on ne pense pas par des mots. Quant à _exprimer_ et _affirmer_, bien _exprimer des mots_ me semble un peu incongru, parfois on a _en des termes_, ou ce sont les mots qui expriment la pensée ou l'on s'exprime par la parole non ? Je ne suis pas certain, mais je suis d'avis que c'est bien plus usuel avec _entendre_ (comprendre/interpréter) et _dire_. Merci.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax dire et entendre sont en effet les plus courants.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning "beaucoup":

In French, "beaucoup" is an adverb, not a noun, so you can't say "un beaucoup". You can say for example:

> J'aime beaucoup le chocolat. -> I like chocolate very much.
>
> J'ai beaucoup dormi. -> I have slept a lot.

For your example I suggest you use "grandement":

> Cela peut grandement améliorer ta mémoire -> This can improve your memory by a lot.

If you mean that it can improve a big proportion of the whole memory not necessary in a big amount of improvement, you can say:

> Cela peut améliorer beaucoup de ta mémoire -> This can improve a lot of your memory.

That last formulation sounds weird, but it is because the sense is weird itself.